# How to calculate records inside a for loop with sqlite and rowcount

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter

I'm having a hard time with Twitter API, I'm using the code below to fetch a number of tweets but everytime I got a different number of tweets ( it really depends on several parametres : lang, popular/recent, filter, etc .. )

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=str(keyword), 
       result_type='recent', lang="en").items(num_tweets):
```

The goal here is to have a number of tweets (in this example it's 10 with 50 been requested from Twitter ) in a database after text procesing, calculations, etc..

I'm using this code but I'm not sure if it's the best way to include 2 if statements and I don't know where to put the empty lists..

```
    num_tweets = 50
    final = tweet.text

    words = len(final.split()) # To delete short tweets
    nline = keyword,final      # Values for db

    if (words > 15):
        cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tweets (keyword, tweet) VALUES (?, ?)', (nline))
        conn.commit()

        rows_affected=cursor.rowcount
        # print (rows_affected)

        if (rows_affected == 1):
            stored = []
            exact = len(stored)
            stored.append(final)
            print ('Tweet Stored')
            print (len(stored))


        else:
            pass

            if (exact < 10):
                # print (exact)
                continue
            else:
                break
```

What if my code find only 9 tweets and the `stored` list never reach the desired result? Should I use something like `=<` ?

My attempt is to add `LIMIT 10` in the `INSERT` to db code ... and use `rowcount`

Comment: You will need to sort out any syntax errors so that you can run the code and provide us with both the actual output **and** the output you require.

Comment: @quamrana Sorry, I updated the question, actually it's working (no syntax errors ) but only 9 tweets are stored to the db..

Comment: You've now lost your assignment to `exact`, but I suspect you are not accumulating the count of how many tweets you store in total across all iterations.

Comment: @quamrana Yes I lost the assignement, I tried all the possible combinations.. It's my first time working with multiple if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
num_tweets = 50
keyword = "Aventador"

stored = []
exact = len(stored)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=str(keyword), result_type='recent', lang="en").items(num_tweets):
    final = tweet.text

    words = len(final.split())
    nline = keyword,final
    all.append(final)

    if (words > 15):
        rows_affected=cursor.rowcount
        cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tweets (keyword, tweet) VALUES (?, ?)', (nline))
        conn.commit()

        # print (rows_affected)

        if (rows_affected == 1):
            stored.append(final)
            print ('Tweet Stored')         
        else:
            pass

    if (len(stored) < 10):
        print ('Continue')
        continue
    else:
        print ('Script Break!')
        break 

print ('   ')
print ('Number of Tweets fetched:')
print (len(all))

print ('   ')
print ('Stored Tweets:')
print (len(stored))
```

Comment: So what you did in the end had not much to do with if statements and more about placing `stored=[]` outside the loop.

Comment: @quamrana Yes, it's my first time working with a LOT of variables. Thanks btw.